# Class forcings and elementary embeddings

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

In the Hamkins-Kirmayer-Perlmutter paper "Generalizations Of The Kunen Inconsistency", they prove the following theorem:

"Theorem 7:  In any set forcing extension $V[G]$, there is no nontrivial elementary embedding $j:$$V$$\rightarrow$$V[G]$ [$V$$\vDash$$ZFC$--my comment].

They note:

"Attribution for this... theorem is not clear to us.  It may have been known to Woodin, and Matt Foreman mentioned to the first author that he had discussed a version of it with Mack Stanley and Sy Friedman in the 1980's, but their proof was different from ours here and their result unpublished$.^{2}$"

Here is their footnote [2]:

"Part of their focus was reportedly on the extent to which the result generalized to class forcing.  For example, they considered the case of class forcing extensions by amenable class forcings.  Foreman mentioned that  Woodin has an example of forcing using a class version of non-stationary tower forcing where $j:$$V$$\rightarrow$$V[G]$, but $V[G]$ does not have $ZFC$ for for the predicate $V$...."

[Edit]  Apparently, one has that when replaces 'set forcing' with 'class forcing' in Theorem 7, one can have a nontrivial elementary embedding $j:$$V$$\rightarrow$$V[G]$.  This seems to contradict Kunen's inconsistency, but the comments made seem to say no.  Why is this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What the footnote says is that $V[G]$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but it is not assumed that it satisfies its strengthening where in the replacement schema we can use a (new) symbol for $V$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  I might have to delete and rewrite the question.  Thanks.  One question for you, though.  Does the footnote imply from its context, (in your opinion) that in Woodin's example, $j$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding?  From its context, it appears to me to (at least) imply just that.

Comment: Yes, $j$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding (in the usual language with only membership and no extra symbols).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  Then in a class version of non-stationary tower forcing (Woodin's example) $V$,$V[G]$$\vDash$$ZFC$ and there is a nontrivial elementary embedding $j:$$V$$\rightarrow$$V[G]$?  How does this example get around the Kunen inconsistency?  Do Reinhardt cardinals exist in this class model?  By the way, in Woodin's example, what is the generic object $G$?

Comment: In stationary tower forcing, the generic $G$ is an ultrafilter.

Comment: @CarloVonSchnitzel: Yes, but in stationary tower forcing, the generic ultrafilter $G$ defines a generic elementary embedding $j$, which, in the case of the Woodin example, is the nontrivial $j:$$V$$\rightarrow$$V[G]$, correct?  Also, in the Woodin example in question, $V$$\vDash$$ZFC$ ?

Comment: $V$ is the universe of all sets, so $V$ satisfies $ZFC$. As Andres pointed out, the meaning of the remark is that you can't use $V$ as a predicate in formulas when working in $V[G]$. That $V[G]$ satisfies $ZFC$ is just from basic forcing considerations...

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Re: your comment, how do you *think* it contradicts Kunen inconsistency? Kunen applies (on the face of it) only to embeddings from $V$ into $V$, not into some other $W$. We can with some work extend Kunen to rule out embeddings from $V$ into *set-generic* extensions, but set-generic and class-generic extensions are very different, so this doesn't address embeddings of $V$ into class-generic extensions at all.

Comment: By the way, I disagree with the votes to close: this is a question around subtle issues (class vs. set genericity, elementary embeddings of universes), and I think it's appropriate for MO.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  If I am understanding correctly (and I may not be understanding correctly) Wooden's example (since it is a form of tower forcing) the generic object $G$ defines a generic elementary embedding $j$ from $V$ into $V[G]$, both models of $ZFC$.  From the context of the footnote (and this seems to be the consensus of the commentators), $j$ is nontrivial.  Since the only generic object added to $V$ by $V[G]$ seems to be the nonrivial elementary embedding $j$ (here is where I would like someone familiar with Woodin's unpublished result to step up to the plate and tell me if I have

Comment: (cont.) misunderstood the result), this would seem to imply that there exists a nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ into $V$ ($V$ a model of $ZFC$), contradicting Kunen's inconsistency (note that since Kunen formulated his result in $MK$, $j$ could be an elementary embedding from the proper class $V$ into itself).  What, if anything, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: How do you get an embedding from $V$ into $V$, from an embedding from $V$ into $V[G]$? That is, can you expand on "this would seem . . . from $V$ into $V$"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  That is why, in my original question I asked re. Woodin's example, "what is the generic object $G$?". Doesn't $G$ define merely the generic nontrivial embedding $j$ and nothing else?

Comment: I'm not really sure how that's relevant, to be honest. Let me put it this way. Suppose I give you an elementary embedding $j$ from $V$ into a class-generic extension $V[G]$. Do you believe you can get an elementary embedding $h$ from $V$ into $V$, from $j$ somehow? If so, how? If not, then there must be something specific about Woodin's forcing that makes you believe you can get such an $h$ from his $j$ - what is that?

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Well, since $V$$\subset$$V[G]$, wouldn't nontrivial $j:$$V$$\rightarrow$$V[G]$ also be a nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ into $V$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin No - the embedding $j$ will send things in $V$ to things outside $V$. Note that this requires $V$ to not be definable in $V[G]$, which is where **set** forcing is different.

Comment: Here is a link to the paper Thomas is asking about: http://jdh.hamkins.org/generalizationsofkuneninconsistency/. Follow through to the arxiv for a pdf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we have an elementary embedding $j: V\rightarrow V[G]$; why should we expect $ran(j)\subset V$? This would only need to be true if $V$ were definable in $V[G]$. Now, by a theorem of Laver (and independently Woodin, I think) $V$ is indeed definable in any **set**-generic extension, but this fails dramatically for **class**-generic extensions; see [Definability of ground model](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83203/definability-of-ground-model). And indeed, I believe Woodin’s elementary embedding sends some things in $V$ outside of $V$. EDIT: this belief is correct, see Joel's comment below.

---

By the way, note that even if we knew $ran(j)\subset V$, there is in principal a second obstacle which could arise: restricting the codomain can kill elementarity! Exercise: we can construct structures $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{B}$ in a language with one binary function symbol $f$ and an elementary embedding $j: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ with $ran(j)\subset\mathcal{A}$, such that for some $a\in\mathcal{A}$ we have:

- $\mathcal{A}\models\neg\exists y\forall z f(y, z)=a$,
- $\mathcal{B}\models\neg\exists y\forall z f(y, z)=j(a),$ but
- there is some $b\in\mathcal{A}$ such that for all $c\in\mathcal{A}$, $f(b, c)=j(a)$.

(Note that we will necessarily have $\mathcal{A}\not\prec\mathcal{B}$.) This obstacle is the reason Theorem 7 of Hamkins-Kirmayer-Perlmutter isn't a one-line corollary of Laver's theorem.

Comment: If $V$ and $V[G]$ are distinct, then you can never have $\text{ran}(j)\subset V$, since $j(V_\alpha)$ must be equal to $(V[G])_{j(\alpha)}$ by elementarity, and for large enough $\alpha$, this is not contained in $V$.

Comment: The same argument shows that your point about restricting the codomain *always* occurs: if $j:V\to M$ is elementary and $N\subsetneq M$, then $\text{ran}(j)$ is not contained in $N$, since $j(V_\alpha)=V_{j(\alpha)}^M$, which will not be in $N$ for large enough $\alpha$.

Comment: Does this mean that for certain class forcings, the full elementary diagram of $V$ (relativised to predicate) is not definable in $V[G]$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Certainly not - for example, consider the trivial forcing extension $V[G]=V$. Truth in $V$ is very much not definable in $V[G]$. :P More generally, I suspect that it is much harder (if possible at all) to build a class- or set-generic extension $V[G]$ in which $Th(V)$ is definable. (Note that there's an apparent proof of impossibility: since the forcing relation is definable in $V$, shouldn't $Th(V[G], G)$ be definable in $V[G]$ from the parameter $G$ if $Th(V)$ is definable in $V[G]$? However, this breaks down since the forcing relation is not **uniformly** definable.)

Comment: (But I might be misunderstanding what you're asking - what do you mean by "relativized to a predicate"?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: It is a paraphrase of a statement made by Prof. Hamkins in a slide presentation titled "The set-theoretic multiverse:  a model-theoretic philosophy of set theory."  presented at the Philosophy and Model Theory Conference, Paris, June 2-5, 2010.  It is regarding the Naturalist Account of Forcing.  The slide reads as follows:  "Suppose that $V$ is a universe of set theory and $\mathbb P$ is a notion of forcing.  Then there is a class model of the theory expressing what it means to be the corresponding forcing extension.

Comment: (cont.) Namely, the theory keeps everything true in $V$, relativised to a class predicate, and also asserts that there is a $V$-generic filter.  [New Paragraph] The language has $\in$, constant symbols for every element of $V$, a predicate for $V$, and constant symbol $G$.  The theory asserts:  1. The full elementary diagram of $V$, relativised to predicate.  2. The assertion that $V$ is a transitive proper class.  3. $G$ is a $V$-generic ultrafilter.  4.$ZFC$ holds, and the new universe is $V[G]$."  Is this class model a model of set forcing, class forcing, or both?

Comment: (cont.) Sorry I didn't respond sooner.